# AngularJS Binding a changing value from a service to scope value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io, promise, q

I have a factory which holds a collection. This collection is constantly updated by pushing incoming values from socket.io. I would like to return this collection to a scope variable which automatically updates. I don't like to use callbacks in the controller. I would like the same behavior like with a defer.resolve(collection ).I know i could use defer.notify(collection) but then i need something like

```
service.update().then(null, null, function(collection){
    $scope.collection = collection()
}
```

which is quite ugly. With promise resolve i just can do

```
$scope.collection = service.collection()
```

But this this updates the service only once. So how can i achieve this using promises or another technique ?

Answer (score 0):

Angular promises no longer auto unwrap  (from 1.2.0-rc.3 I think), I don't see something ugly there.

If your service is async and returns promise like:

```
app.factory('service', function ($http, $q) { 

    return{
        update: function () { 

            var deferred = $q.defer();

           //....
           .success(function (data) {
                      deferred.resolve(data);
                }).error(function() {
                deferred.reject("Error ...");
            });
            //Returning the promise object
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

The controller will look like:

```
service.update()   // returns promise
       .then(function (result) {
          //.....                          
         }, function (result) {
           alert("Error: No data returned");
          });
```

Comment: That's what i am doing no. But i use only defer.notify not resolve if  you call resolve, its not possible to get further updates anymore. I'm not sure if it's a good practice, since the promise never gets resolved

Answer (score 0):

You can use $broadcast for this. Whenever your service changes the collection you can use

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('X:changed');
```

And on the controller

```
$scope.$on('X:changed', _reassign);
function _reassign() {
    $scope.X = Service.X;
}
```